# Why is the thread switching in this RxJava code in my android repository

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, rx-java

I cannot for the life of me figure out why the threads are switching in my code that makes use of Rx-Java. This is in android and I am using RxJava3. I have a Repository that calls an api using RetroFit2 with a RxJava calladapter in order to return objects wrapped in RxJava classes. I'll apologize beforehand for the awful renaming of my code, I wasn't too creative in that regard, so I apologize if it is hard to follow because of the renaming of variables, methods and classes.

Here is my RetroFit2 with a Rxjava calladapter as well as the Schedulers.io set as the threadpool for the Singles to execute on:

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(LOCAL_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
            .build();
```

And my RetroFit interface has this method:

```
@GET("url/{data-id}")
Single<FirstObject> getFirstObject(@Path("data-id") Long dataID);
```

I return a Single from my apiService attribute (using the above retrofit) of my repository in a fetchData method. I then make use of the SingleSubject class in order to eagerly fetch the api call by subscribing in the fetchData method. I also eagerly do a bunch of filtering into data I will need in my app by, again, subscribing more subjects to this initial subject. I am using the subjects in order to execute this code in the Repository layer and have it ready for my various ViewModels that need to make use of this data, instead of executing it multiple times for each ViewModel. My Repository layer is a Singleton and exists from the beginning of the program till the end(using a Hilt annotation).

Here is the constructor and attributes of my Repository layer:

```
ApiService apiService;
SingleSubject<FirstObject> firstSubject;
SingleSubject<List<DerivedObject1>> derivedSubject1;
SingleSubject<DerivedObject1> firstFilteredDerivedSubject1;
SingleSubject<DerivedObject1> secondFilteredDerivedSubject1;
SingleSubject<List<DerivedObject2>> derivedSubject2;
SingleSubject<List<DerivedObject2>> filteredDerivedSubject2;


@Inject
public Repository(ApiService apiService){
    this.apiService = apiService;
    firstSubject = SingleSubject.create();
    derivedSubject1 = SingleSubject.create();
    derivedSubject2 = SingleSubject.create();
    firstFilteredDerivedSubject1 = SingleSubject.create();
    secondFilteredDerivedSubject1 = SingleSubject.create();
    filteredDerivedSubject2 = SingleSubject.create();

}
```

Here is the fetchData method where I eagerly execute the API call and necessary filtering with RxJava:

```
public void fetchData(Long dataId){
    System.out.println("" + "Main thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    apiService.getSingle(dataId).retry(1).subscribe(firstSubject);
    firstSubject
            .map(FirstObject::getDerivedObject1).subscribe(derivedSubject1);
    firstSubject.map(FirstObject::getDerivedObject2).subscribe(derivedSubject2);
    Observable<DerivedObject1> tempObservable = derivedSubject1.toObservable()
            .concatMapIterable(list -> list).publish().autoConnect(2);
    Single.fromObservable(tempObservable
            .filter(firstObject -> firstObject.getBoolean) && firstObject.getOtherBoolean))
            .subscribe(secondFilteredDerivedSubject1);
    Single.fromObservable(tempObservable
            .filter(firstObject -> firstObject.getBoolean && firstObject.getAnotherBoolean))
            .subscribe(firstFilteredDerivedSubject1);
    derivedSubject2.toObservable().concatMapIterable(list -> list)
            .filter(DerivedObject2::getBoolean).toList()
            .subscribe(filteredDerivedSubject2);
            
    // FOR DEBUG PURPOSES
    //testing firstSubject subscription
    firstSubject.subscribe(i -> System.out.println("firstSubject subscription
            IN FETCHDATA, CURRENT THREAD: " + Thread.currentThread()
            .getId()));
            
    //testing filteredDerivedSubject2 subscription
    filteredDerivedSubject2
            .subscribe(i -> System.out.println("filtedDerivedSubject2 subscription
            IN FETCHDATA, CURRENT THREAD: " + Thread.currentThread()
            .getId()));

}
```

If you notice, I have a print statement that prints out the ID as 2 for the "Main Thread". I call the fetchData method from a ViewModel which is executed on the Main Thread, so it prints out 2 which is the Main Thread in Android. At the bottom I subscribe to a couple of these subjects in order to test the threading. As I would expect, the threads are some high number in the 500s signifying that it is not subscribing on the main thread and using some Thread in Schedulers.io().

However, then when I get into a new Activity, and a new ViewModel, I call the getFilteredDerivedSubject2 method that also resides in the same Repository class as the fetchData and aforementioned constructor and attributes. This other ViewModel again calls this getFilteredDerivedSubject2 method on the Main Thread. It actually returns a Single instead of a SingleSubject as I want only the functionality of a Single in my ViewModel. Its purpose is to just return the Single.

Here is the getFilteredDerivedSubject2 method:

```
public Single<List<DerivedObject2>> getfilteredDerivedSubject2(){

    // FOR DEBUG PURPOSES
    System.out.println("In CURRENT THREAD: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    //testing firstSubject subscription
    firstSubject.subscribe(i -> System.out.println("firstSubject subscription
            IN GETFILTEREDDERIVEDSUBJECT2 CURRENT THREAD: " + Thread.currentThread().getId()));
            
    //testing filteredDerivedSubject2 subscription
    filteredDerivedSubject2
            .subscribe(i -> System.out.println("filtedDerivedSubject2 subscription 
            IN GETFILTEREDDERIVEDSUBJECT2 CURRENT THREAD: " + Thread.currentThread()
            .getId()));
            
            
    // REAL PURPOSE OF METHOD
    return filteredDerivedSubject2;
}
```

As you can see, I again have some debugging print statements and subscriptions in order to test the threads. Here as expected, the first print statement prints out that it is in the Main Thread with the ID of "2". That was expected as I again call this method from the Main Thread. Then however, the subscriptions that print out the Thread also print out the Main Thread with an ID of 2. I have no idea why. I never change any kind of threading with subscribeOn nor observeOn. I would completely expect it to keep staying on the same Thread in the 500s or whatever for each subject I subscribe to. It does not. It prints out that its Thread ID is 2.

Does anybody know why this is? I understand I can fix it with a subscribeOn or observeOn operator, but I would really like to understand why the Threading is behaving this way. I am an RxJava noob. Thanks for any replies!

EDIT: Here is the output from the print statements that were requested:

```
I/System.out: Main thread ID: 2
I/System.out: firstSubject subscription IN FETCHDATA, CURRENT THREAD: 224
filtedDerivedSubject2 subscription IN FETCHDATA, CURRENT THREAD: 224
I/System.out: in CURRENT THREAD: 2
I/System.out: firstSubject subscription IN GETFILTEREDDERIVEDSUBJECT2 
CURRENT THREAD: 2
I/System.out: filtedDerivedSubject2 subscription IN 
GETFILTEREDDERIVEDSUBJECT2 CURRENT THREAD: 2
```

These are all the relevant print statements that are the result of the print statements in the code I posted. For clarification the "in CURRENT THREAD: 2" is the first print statement in the getfilteredDerivedSubject2 method.

Comment: To achieve what you want here, you never needed even 1 subject, and your code would probably have less oddities if you didn't have multiple subscriptions that are unmanaged.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Can you explain how so? As I said, I am not experienced. And just to clarify, there are getters for each of my SingleSubjects with a Single return type, not just the one getter that I have in code.

Comment: @programmingmanwithaplan one thing I'm not understanding from your question. Do you expect that subscribing to `firstSubject` would be in io? because nowhere in the code you tell it to do that, so subscription will happen on the thread that it was called from. What you did is changed the subscriptions for the retrofit calls.

Comment: @Fred So, when I execute this code, the Single returned from Retrofit executes on a thread in the Schedulers.io() threadpool. Through testing with these subjects, it appears that the subject subscribed to that Retrofit Single like firstSubject then has its own subscription occur on the the same thread. filteredDerivedSubject2 displays the exact same behavior after subscribing to firstSubject. They print out the same ID which is not the Main Thread ID of 2. This happens however only in the fetchData method (fetchData is called from the Main Thread (ID: 2).

Comment: @Fred However, in the getfilteredDerivedSubject2() method, which is also called from the Main Thread (ID: 2), the subscriptions happen on the Main Thread as evidenced by their subscriptions printing out ID: 2 when testing. I do not understand why this is. I am just trying to understand the behavior of the threading and why it is different in each of the above methods. I likely could add in a subscribeOn somewhere to fix this, but I am just trying to understand the general rules of how the threading works with these subjects.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Any way you want to point me in the right direction of how to accomplish this in a better way? I agree this code feels kind of ugly.

Comment: You are looking for the operator called `Single.zip` to wait for the emission of all provided `Single`s. If you intend to cache the results of the operations, consider saving the results in the subscriber into `BehaviorRelay`s. See http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html . Once they are persisted, you can wait for the emission of [any] (not all) of those relays using `Observable.combineLatest()`. You are practically *never* supposed to have a `.subscribe` call where the `Disposable` is not saved into a `CompositeDisposable` (that is eventually `.clear()`'d).

Comment: @programmingmanwithaplan you configure retrofit to subscribe by default on io, that's why the returned single subscribes in io. However, nothing of the sorts or any explicit `subscribeOn` is being called for the subjects you have there. What I'm not fully getting is if you expected something different. At the end of the day, these are different subscriptions from retrofit.

Comment: Basically, what I'm confused is that you say "as expected the numbers are somewhere in the 500s which indicates they are in another thread" and to be honest to me this isn't really expected. I would expect these to also print 2. Any chance we could see an example of the print statements? Of the output I mean.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I am not sure if I am misunderstanding how to use the things you are talking about or you are misunderstanding my intent. The Repository I am using is a singleton so I figured each subscription would be disposed of itself once the app is killed, but maybe this is bad practice and I am overlooking something. What I am trying to do is make one retrofit call to return a single. Then I use the SingleSubjects in order to filter this original single into multiple SingleSubects with different filtered data.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Each SingleSubject is returned to various ViewModels/Activities to be used for a specific purpose. I use the Subjects in order to subscribe so as to immediately execute the filtering and not wait for each chain to execute when a specific ViewModel calls a getter and subscribes to it. This also caches the differing filtered data. Each of the various SingleSubjects you see in the fetchData method are necessary for different ViewModels and I have getters for each of them. I am unsure how zip, BehaviorRelay and combineLatest would help, but I admit I may not understand enough.

Comment: @Fred I just added what the output was into my post as an EDIT. I only say this is expected, because when messing around in a little testing android studio project I have, I could replicate this behavior of the subscribing subject (to a Single) to then have its own subscriptions occur on the same thread that it itself had subscribed to. So that is why I expected it. I cannot see anything different with the second method call to have it behave differently other than being executed later. The method still is called on the main thread.

Comment: @Fred But from some testing I did, and the fetchData method, it appears that if a Subject is subscribed to an Observable, whatever thread the Observable was set to, the Subject will then occur on this thread as well when it is being subscribed to (barring any other subscribeOn/ObserveOn operators). This happens in fetchData but not in my other method. I guess "expected" is not great word choice as I am unsure why it is happening in one case and not the other.

Comment: @programmingmanwithaplan sorry for the late reply. I cannot duplicate the results you got. Every example project I create I get consistently the expected threads (well, expected according to my own believes :D ) - `main` when you subscribe to subjects and an `io` thread when you subscribe to the api service. Is it possible that there's more code messing with the subjects?

Comment: @Fred I just tried it again, just to make sure, I am still getting the subject that subscribes to the single on in a non main thread way in the hundreds. Retrofit is created with Schedulers.io(). All I have is the retrofit interface returning a Single, a repository class that handles the retrofit calling of API which then returns the Single to a method within the MainActivity, and in that MainActivity, a SingleSubject that subscribes to the Single. The SingleSubject is then subscribed to with a print statement printing out the Thread ID. I dont know why we are getting different results haha.

Comment: @programmingmanwithaplan I'm really sorry but I don't know what's up. The Rx call adapter simply calls `observable.subscribeOn(scheduler)` on the retrofit observable. I can't really help :|